# why I Can't drop NAN values with dropna() function in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

> simple i make pandas  data frame from dictionary then use dropna
> I dont know why its not removing NaN

```
df=pd.DataFrame(dic)
df.dropna(axis=1,inplace=True)
df.head()
```

[image: Image of Output with code]

> my code link(not completed)
> https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HoniG14dUZbERxDm9QKowjkpacK3wyt5?usp=sharing

Comment: please provide the output of `dic`. Chances are you have strings and not real NaNs

Comment: Thanks , actually you are right i checked and found that files has nan string not real nans

Comment: Then I guess you can delete ;)

Comment: Should i delete the question ? after problam get solved

Comment: Up to you, I thought this would likely have been answered before but I didn't find a strict duplicate (most dropna issues seem to be due to lack of assignment). I'll provide an answer, if you find a duplicate let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely have "NaN" strings. You should first convert them to real NA values. Let's use `pd.NA`:

```
df = df.replace('NaN', pd.NA).dropna(axis=1)
```